# Implement the Filter method on a Prototype

Tags: javascript, for-loop, filter, prototype

I have to filter a prototype without using the `.filter` method.
I thought that I had it, but it gave me a mistake in one of the tests, I checked the answer, but I don't fully understand it and when i searched for it, my answer is the only one that appears.

> Write your own `Array.prototype.myFilter()`, which should behave exactly like `Array.prototype.filter()`. You should not use the built-in filter method. The Array instance can be accessed in the `myFilter` method using `this`.

This is the Prop:

```
Array.prototype.myFilter = function(callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  // Only change code below this line

  // Only change code above this line
  return newArray;
};
```

This is the answer they need:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
  if(Boolean(callback(this[i], i, this)) === true){
  newArray.push(this[i])
  }
}
```

This is the answer i came up with:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
  if(callback(this[i]){
  newArray.push(this[i])
  }
}
```

This are the Tests:

```
Passed:[23, 65, 98, 5, 13].myFilter(item => item % 2) should equal [23, 65, 5, 13].
Passed:["naomi", "quincy", "camperbot"].myFilter(element => element === "naomi") should return ["naomi"].
Failed:[1, 1, 2, 5, 2].myFilter((element, index, array) => array.indexOf(element) === index) should return [1, 2, 5].
Passed:Your code should not use the filter method.`
```

I don't understand this part

`(this[i], i, this)`

Comment: The test says that when using the second parameter of the callback, the code does not work. Given that your code does not pass the second argument to the callback, that's not surprising.

Comment: The callback to filter function gets three arguments, first is the current element, then it's index and then the entire array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters

Comment: So conditon should be `if(callback(this[i], i, this)) newArray.push(this[i])`

Comment: @DecPK  The solution is in the question.

Comment: `(this[i], i, this)`     `this[i]` The element your checking,  `i` The index in the array,  `this` The array itself.

Comment: @Keith I didn't see it.

Comment: to make it more complicated, `filter` accepts two arguments, the second one is `thisArgs` and the solution does not reflect this, but uses strange boolean conversions and checking with superfluous strict comparison with `true`.

Comment: `if (Boolean(…) === true)` is a horrible answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback for [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) accepts three arguments:

- `element` the current element
- `index` the index of the element
- `array` the array being iterated on

What is asked of you is to make `myFilter` behave **exactly** like `filter`. Therefore you cannot omit these arguments when calling the user's predicate:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
  if(callback(this[i], i, this)){
    newArray.push(this[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been wrecking my brain for an hour, and when you explained it, it suddenly clicked and it's SO obvious, thanks a lot!